# JQuery offset doesn't set

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm developing, as an amateur, a wordpress site.

I've put the script below directly in the `<head>`. I want it first to work before I enqueue it the correct way.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#cta-section').waypoint(function() {
            jQuery('#cta-section').toggleClass('animate-cta');
        }, {offset: '80%'});
    });
</script>
```

I keep getting the following errors:

```
(index):13 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).waypoint is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):13)
at j (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.min.js:2)


(index):963 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).waypoint is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):963)
at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

Comment: Define `this isn't working`. Any errors? Wrong output? etc, etc. There's nothing really to go on here.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put my errors in the post.

Comment: from where you get `.waypoint ()`? do you used extra library which have this function?

Comment: Ah no. I wasn't aware I need to do this. How do I do it?

Comment: You need to load in the `waypoint` lib before your snippet, which is why you use enqueue. You use the dependencies array to define what is needed for your script and therefore WP will position it properly, not just where you think it should be.

Comment: @AlivetoDie Doesn't give me an error but the cta-section action happens on loading, not on scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The only annoying point is that I need to play around with the `ShrinkOn` numbers.
    <

```
script>
        function resizeCTAOnScroll() {
            const distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 1850,
            headerEl = document.getElementById('cta-section');

            if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
                headerEl.classList.add("animate-cta");
            } else {
                headerEl.classList.remove("animate-cta");
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', resizeCTAOnScroll);
    </script>
```